# What is (a+b)^x called?

Tags: exponentiation

I'm wondering what (a+b)^x is called. I will need this information to study for a test, but I could not manage to Google this one out. Specifically, I need to know (a+b)^2 and (a+b)^3 are.

While we're on the topic, I'm wondering how you expand the latter.
Is it something like:

(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)=
a^3+a^2b+a^2b+ab^2+b^3+b^2*a+b^2+a*ba^2

Or am I wrong?

Thanks,
H. Z.

P.S. I know that ^^ isn't completely simplified (if it's even correct)

Comment: See the Binomial Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: Thanks. How could I forget?!

Comment: $(a+b)^2$ expands to $a^2+2ab+b^2$. Often needed. And $(a+b)^3$ expands to $a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$. You had gotten most of the terms but not all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be called the *binomial expansion* or the *binomial theorem*. When $x$ is a positive integer, we have the well-known relationship

$$(a+b)^x = \sum_{k=0}^x \begin{pmatrix} x \\ k \end{pmatrix} a^k b^{x-k}.$$

The quantity $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ k\end{pmatrix} = \frac{x!}{k!(x-k)!}$ is known as the *binomial coefficient*.

When $x$ is non-integral, it gets substantially more complex. We replace the binomial coefficient with a form using a Pochhammer symbol and turn the series into an infinite series, which generalizes the expansion to all reals but non-negative integers (and in fact complex numbers, too).

Comment: I love me some complex exponents without Euler's famed exponential formula.  ;-)